# Convert javascript generated date string to different string in JS or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, date

everyone

my problem is that my JS code generates date in format

"Thu Jan 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)"

and I need to convert it to format like this

"2013-01-10"

either in JS or PHP, because I'm storing dates in DB in this format. My first thought was to convert it to timestamp, then timestamp convert to new date string, but date or string functions can't read that kind of date format, so propably need to pregreplace some things and thats it.

Comment: Can you post some code please

Comment: Have you tried anything? Anything at all?

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/jrujDx

Comment: @PLB post your code as answer.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I hate posting one line answers and there are three answers already. ;) Also there are hundreds of duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can format date in JavaScript:

```
function formatDate(date) {
   var year = date.getFullYear(),
       month = date.getMonth() + 1,
       day = date.getDate();
   if (month.toString().length === 1) {
      month = '0' + month;
   }
   if (day.toString().length === 1) {
      day = '0' + day;
   }
   return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
formatDate(new Date("Thu Jan 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)"));
//"2013-01-10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about php `strtotime`.

```
<?php

$date_str = "Thu Jan 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200";

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [date.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) for conversions.

```
var myDate = new Date("Thu Jan 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)").toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log(myDate); //2013-01-10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript code to get date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    document.write("" +year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to:

```
var date = new Date("Thu Jan 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)"),
    month,
    day,
    date_string;

date_string = date.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ((month = date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' +
    ((day = date.getDate()) < 10 ? '0' + day : day);
```

date_string now holds the value of "2013-01-10".